# DIV Внутри DIV-a

Tags: вёрстка, html

Как сделать так, чтобы *DIV* который находится внутри основного *DIV*-a, выделялся на нем только в определенном месте? Выглядит это так: основной *DIV* небольшого размера, в то время как дочерний див, размером на длину страницы. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы часть дочернего была видна на определенной части, у основного дива.  Конкретно - по центру, а остальная часть была ЗА НИМ!
Сам еще не разбираюсь, сильно не ругайтесь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой пример как это сделать:

```css
.outer{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #999999;
}
.inner{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 175px;
  background-color: #D8D9DD;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

*Если у вас один элемент закрывает другой, используйте **z-index**(в css стилях, например z-index: 27), это для для того элемента который должен накладываться сверху. Это свойство работает только для элементов, у которых значение **position** задано как absolute, fixed или relative.

Answer (score 0):

```css
section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3em 10%;
  background: silver;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  height: 3em;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```